# Android client listener for server notification

Tags: android, mysql, gps

I am developing a Bus navigation app , where a user asks for bus gps data through a server, the server makes calculations on speed and time intervals and sends the data back to the student. So far i used standard json POST/GET to send receive data from user side to the server, all of which were initiated by the user. now, however , i need the server to communicate with the bus side of the app, and ask for GPS data. thus i need some form of listener class in the bus side, but i dont know what to use. Searching through the forum I only found GCM as a possible solution.

My question: how to implement a listener class in the bus side to listen to server notifications, is GCM the best solution available? if not what otehr options do i have?:)

notes:

platform is android

Client side : android (User and bus driver are on the same app)

Server side: php

database: Mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is GCM. 
Otherwise you might drawn the users battery on polling your server.
Also GCM is very fast and reliable.